# Although thermodynamically feasible, in practice, magnesium metal is not used for the reduction of alumina in the metallurgy of auminium. Why?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Everyone knows:
$$\ce{Mg +Al2O3->MgO +Al}$$
This reaction is thermodynamically feasible.
Use can we this for reduction of Alumina. And produce Aluminium. Then why don't we not use this why?

Answer (score 4):

If you compare the [magnesium price](http://www.metalprices.com/p/MagnesiumFreeChart) (about 2$ per pound)

to the [aluminum price](http://www.metalprices.com/p/AluminumFreeChart) (about $0.80 per pound)

you can see it is unprofitable.

Even considering the elements' relative atomic weight, you would still be losing money if you did that.

Comment: not everyone uses '$' or 'pound'

Comment: @ADG regardless of the currency used, the fact remains that magnesium is more expensive than aluminium.

Comment: @santiago Dave already mentioned "Even considering the elements' relative atomic weight, you would still be losing money if you did that."

Comment: @ADG, my comment was in reference to your comment obviously